# jQuery timepicker does not want to display alongside a datepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use a jQuery timepicker from the web in my form, but for some reason it doesen't work at all.

I also have a text box on top for a jQuery datepicker, and that works, so I dont know what the problem could be. Here are my links for both:

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
    <title>Beauty Factory Bookings</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- links for jquery datepicker -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>

    <!-- links for jquery timepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</head>
```

Then, here is my javascript and html code for both of them:

```
<div class="heading2">
    <p>Select Your Date:</p>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Date"/>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
            });
        </script>

</div>

<div class="heading3">
    <p>Select Your Time:</p>
        <input name="time" value=""/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input[name="time"]').ptTimeSelect();
            });
        </script>

</div>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this, causing the timepicker not to display at all?

Here is the website where I got the code from for the timepicker:

http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html

Comment: Try to initialize the date picker in your document ready

Comment: @JorgeMejia What do you mean?

Comment: I doubt there is something conflict between timepicker and datepicker, have you try timepicker and just retain datepicker and check whether it works or not.

Comment: @梁少峰 I did that, it still did not work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(function() {
                 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
            });

            $('input[name="time"]').ptTimeSelect();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Still nothing, I click on the input field and nothing appears :/

Comment: You have to initialize the second date time.

Comment: They both come up with a datepicker, and I need the second one to be a time picker :P

Comment: Ok you have to download the source code, from this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/pttimeselect/files/latest/download and then you have to load like this <script type="text/javascript" src="carpet/to/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>

Comment: Remember to import jquery.ptTimeSelect.css and jquery.ptTimeSelect.js

Comment: It works check your css and js tags. I put the code directly but you can use the files jquery.ptTimeSelect .css and .js https://jsfiddle.net/s4vzhu1h/2/

Comment: It doesent work with links for me, so I just used the whole code.